# Dojo How to parse a whole JsonRestStore (JSON to String)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, dojo, store

I set up a  *JsonRestStore* like this:

```
var store = new JsonRestStore({target:"http://localhost:****/blub/"});
```

I get my data with:

```
store.get("rulesets");
```

and the server returns in the console:

```
{"xomName":"loaded","topicName":"Alpha","ioobjectName":"class1","rulesetName":"xmlbinding$45$rules"
},{"xomName":"loaded","topicName":"Beta","ioobjectName":"class2","rulesetName":"xmlbinding$45$rules"
},{"xomName":"loaded","topicName":"gammp","ioobjectName":"class3","rulesetName":"xmlbinding$45$rules"
}]
```

So now i want to parse the whole store (the rulesets).
My suggestion was to do it like this:

```
var memo = new Memory();
memo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(store.get("rulesets")));
console.log(memo);
```

And, as assumed, it didn't worked at all.

So my question is:

Is there a way to parse the whole store?
It would be **amazing**!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your store returns the result as an object. If you want to turn the object to a string you need to use `JSON.stringify`:

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

If you want to turn that string back into an object again you need to use JSON.parse:

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

What you're doing here:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(store.get("rulesets")));
```

Is turning the result object of `store.get("rulesets")` into a string by using `JSON.stringify` and then you're turning the resulting string back in to an object again by using `JSON.parse`. Thus infact the entire line does nothing/undoes itself.

A correct example:

```
// Assign result object to "myObject" variable
var myObject = store.get("rulesets");

// Convert "myObject" to string and assign to variable "myString"
var myString =  JSON.stringify(myObject);

// Convert "myString" to object and assign to variable "myOtherObject"
var myOtherObject = JSON.parse(myString);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your fast answer!
It helps me a lot!